# How to add values from two lists (+extra condition) in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, numbers

I got a problem with this exercise. I've been trying to solve it for a long time searching for stuff, but I am unable to.

Define functions:

```
addLnat :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
mulLnat :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

addLnat adds numbers from two arrays eg.

```
addLnat [4,5,6] [8,5,2] ->  [2,1,9]
```

as [4+8 gives 2 carry 1, 5+5+1 gives 1 carry 1, 6+2+1 = 9]

Lnat, is a "list natural number", represented as a list of base-10 digits, least significant first.  So the number 654 is [4,5,6].

What I got is:

```
addLnat :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addLnat _ [] = []
addLnat [] _ = []
addLnat (x:xs) (y:ys) = (if (x+y) > 9 then x+y-10 else (x+y)):(addLnat xs ys)
```

I adding number and ignoring carry. Not sure how to solve it.
**Any help would be much appreciated.**

---

I have improved the solution as per **user5402** comment, so created addLnat' cr xs ys, but when I what to pass carry as a parameter it fails to load - most probable that I am getting the syntax wrong:(
(cr is 0 only for now and it will be replaced by maths).

```
addLnat' c (x:xs) (y:ys) = d : addLnat' cr xs ys 
where d = if c+x+y < 9 then x+y else c+x+y-((quot (c+x+y) 10)*10) 
cr = 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's a hint: try defining a helper function `addLnatCarry :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]` which takes as a first argument a carry digit (or a `Bool` telling whether there's a carry if you prefer).

Comment: Pro-tip: `[Int]` is _not_ an array. It's a list.

Comment: Thanks - changed array to list in the topic.
It's what I thought , but that was what I was given by someone who knows the stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very good at haskell but maybe this can help ;

```
add::[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
add x y = add' 0 x y
```

There we define a function add that will use add' to add two lists The main idea is to "save" carry and carefully work with corner cases. Here carry is saved in "variable" rest

```
    add'::Int->[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
    add' 0 x []      = x 
    add' rest (x:[]) (y:[]) = [(r `mod` 10),(r `div` 10)]
       where r = x+y+rest
    add' y (x:xs) [] = add' (r `div` 10) ((r `mod` 10):xs) [] 
       where r = x+y
    add' rest (x:xs) (y:ys) = (r `mod` 10) : (add' (r `div` 10) xs ys)
       where r = x+y+rest
```

List x must be bigger than list y but that's not a problem

```
add [5,7,8] [4,3,2]  => [9,0,1,1] (correct)
add [1,2,3] [4,5,6]  => [5,7,9,0] (correct)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a version of addLnat which accepts a carry parameter:

```
addLnat' c (x:xs) (y:ys) = d : addLnat c' xs ys
  where d = if c+x+y > 9 then ... else ...
        c' = ... the next carry bit ...
```

There are a lot more details and corner cases to consider, but this is the basic idea.
Finally,

```
addLnat xs ys = addLnat' 0 xs ys  -- initially the carry is 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :-)
That's the way I took when I was starting with it.
It's what I got working (what doesn't include real carry)
addLnat' c (x:xs) (y:ys) = d : addLnat' 0 xs ys
 where d = if c+x+y < 9 then x+y else c+x+y-((quot (c+x+y) 10)*10)
When I want to include real carry as a variable, it doesn't work 
addLnat' c (x:xs) (y:ys) = d : addLnat' cr xs ys
 where d = if c+x+y < 9 then x+y else c+x+y-((quot (c+x+y) 10)*10)
cr = 0
My guess is wrong syntax, but I cannot get it right :-(